# Characterizing continuity in terms of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

So I know that $f: X \to Y$ is continuous (that is, preimages of open sets are open) is equivalent to either of the following: preimages of closed sets are closed; $f$ is continuous at each point of $X$.

I am wondering what happens if we replace the word "open" in the definition of continuity at a point $x$. Then, is it true that we still have a characterization of continuity? To be precise, what I mean is:

Is it true that $f: X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if for all $x \in X$, and all closed $C \subseteq Y$ containing $f(x)$, there exists a closed $B \subseteq X$ containing $x$ such that $f(B) \subseteq C$?

**My attempt**:

$\implies$: $f$ is continuous so preimages of closed sets are closed. So put $B := f^{-1}(C)$ which is closed and contains $x$. And $f(B) = f(f^{-1}(C)) \subseteq C$.

$\impliedby$: This is where I got stuck. In the proof that I am aware of that continuity at each point implies continuity of the function, we seem to use the result that arbitrary unions of open sets are open. But this isn't necessarily true for closed sets, so I can't just blindly replace the word "open" with "closed". Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Characterisations in terms of closure (not closed sets directly): $f$ is continuous iff $$\forall A \subseteq X: f[\overline{A}]\subseteq \overline{f[A]}$$ iff $$\forall B \subseteq Y: \overline{f^{-1}[B]} \subseteq f^{-1}[\overline{B}]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second implication is not true in general.

If $X$ is a $T_1$ space, $f:X\to Y$ is any function at all, $x\in X$, and $C$ is a closed subset of $Y$ containing $f(x)$, then $\{x\}$ is a closed subset of $X$ containing $x$, and certainly $f[\{x\}]=\{f(x)\}\subseteq C$.

Comment: Thank you. It intrigues me that continuity can be characterized in terms of preimages of closed sets, but not "pointwise" (in the sense given in my question). But being $T_1$ fixes this, seemingly because $T_1$ spaces can "separate points". Do you know some intuition/concepts related to all this? Sorry for this extended comment; I will take time to think about all this more, but couldn't resist this opportunity to wonder what insight you might have.

Comment: @twosigma: I think that you may have it backwards: the $T_1$ property guarantees that every function from $X$ to any space $Y$ has this property, so as long as there is at least one discontinuous function from $X$ to $Y$, there is one that also has the property in question. The reason that *open* cannot be replaced by *closed* in the definition in terms of continuity at each point is roughly that knowing which closed sets contain $x$ doesn’t tell us which open sets contain $x$. But knowing that all preimages of closed sets are closed **does** tell us that all preimages of open sets are open.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is satsified whether or not $f$ is continuous (as long as singleton sets are closed, which is true in metric spaces or just a $T_1$ space). Given any closed set $C$ containing $f(x)$ just take $B=\{x\}$.